# merge two columns into one column and get unique

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have two columns in a table. I need to merge these two columns into 1 column, while making sure all the values in the resulting column are unique (no repetition of the IDs)
 ex:

```
ChildCard    PrimaryCard
123456          123456
123450          123456
123446          123446
123456          123446
156456          155456
157456          155456
121290          124290
234567          204567
```

**Result**

```
CardID
123456
123450
123446
123456
156456
157456
121290
234567
124290
204567
```

Any help would be great here.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you done there? Seems the result is just the childcard. Don't see the "combination of both". Can you clarify please.

Comment: from ChildCard and PrimaryCard you want to form CardID, and it can contain the ChildCard or the PrimaryCard in a way that all CardIDs are unique, is that it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT ChildCard AS CardID FROM tbl UNION SELECT PrimaryCard FROM tbl
```

This should give you a list of distinct card entries, both child and primary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SQL `UNION` command to create a view based on the two sets of data.

`UNION` drops duplicate entries during the merge.
`UNION ALL` keeps duplicate entries.

Refer here for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ChildCard CardID
FROM tbl 
UNION 
SELECT PrimaryCard 
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select distinct IDs like this:

```
SELECT ChildCard AS ResultID FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT PrimaryCard AS ResultID FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your safest option is to use an ID that is just the concatenation of both IDs.

A query to generate all new IDs would be:

```
select PrimaryCard + '_' + ChildCard as CardId
  from your_table;
```